# Bread Didn't Turn Brown

Tags: baking, bread, dough, oven

The bread recipe I followed should have made a bread with a brown-ish top but mine didn't. The output was edible and not raw but the color was pale or light yellowish. What went wrong, was my temperature too low or was it because I turned the fan on inside the oven?

Comment: Please post the recipe and method, pictures would be good too.

Comment: Using the oven fan should result in more browning, rather than less. It is possible that your oven runs (much) colder than the temperature setting has you believe. You could check this using an oven thermometer or infrared thermometer. In general, I would suggest disregarding timings from recipes, but rather baking the bread until it matches the description from the recipe.

Comment: You can get browning at low temperatures -- I've used 300 oF routinely.  Ingredients matter though -- I include 3-6% (bakers percentage) olive oil in the dough.  At those low temps I've found the amount of browning to be proportional to the amount of oil.